# PHP contact form

Tags: php, html, forms

I've looked through a lot of pages to find an answer for my problem. But I can't figure out why my form isn't working. 
I tried different versions of codes from premade examples but I can't get it to work.

This is my php above my form

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message']; 
    $to = 'me@email.com'; 

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $email)) { 
            echo '<p style="color: #27ae60;">Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p style="color: #c0392b;">Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        }
    }
?>
```

and this is my form

```
<form class="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php">

    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Your Name">

    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email">

    <label>Subject</label>
    <input name="subject" placeholder="Your Subject">

    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea class="contact-form-message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">

</form>
```

I've only changed my email in this example here the rest is the same. I'm testing this live on a modern server with php 5+ support

Basicly everything works fine except that I don't get an email. 
I can't find out how to make it work sadly. Any ideas would be cool :/

Edit: GOD DAMNIT IM A TOTAL IDIOT

Gmail Spam filter is strong in this one.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined `$from`.

That is why it is not sending mail.

Also, please check SMTP settings for your machine/server.

[SMTP ports](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php) may not be configured, that is why mail is not sending.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the form:

```
<form class="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php">

    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name">

    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email">

    <label>Subject</label>
    <input name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Your Subject">

    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea class="contact-form-message" type="text" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
```

Also try following this working format:

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

You could just replace the value inside the " " with the post function.

Edit ( This will surely work ):

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $email)) { 
            echo '<p style="color: #27ae60;">Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p style="color: #c0392b;">Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The fourth Parameter for the Mail function is header. Where You can set Mail form and others (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php ).  Please set that, and also check the SMTP configuration as "Programming Student" told you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message']; 
    $to = 'to@test.com'; 
    $from = 'from@test.com'; 

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p style="color: #27ae60;">Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p style="color: #c0392b;">Something went wrong, go back and try again!    </p>'; 
    }

?>
```

You have missed to assign the $from variable

```
<form class="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name">

    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email">

    <label>Subject</label>
    <input name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Your Subject">

    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea class="contact-form-message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message">   </textarea>

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Make sure the php file name "contact.php"

Answer (score 0):

Now My HTML goes this way -->

```html
<body> Fields with * are mandatory. 
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
<fieldset>
<legend>Contact Information</legend>
<p>Name*</p> <input type="text" name="name">
<p>Email*</p> <input type="text" name="email">
</fieldset>
<br />
<br />
<fieldset>
<legend>Other Information</legend>
<p>Website</p> <input type="text" name="website">

<p>Priority</p>
<select name="priority" size="1">
<option value="Low">Low</option>
<option value="Normal">Normal</option>
<option value="High">High</option>
</select>
<br />

<p>Type</p>
<select name="type" size="1">
<option value="update">Contact Us</option>
<option value="change">Information Change</option>
<option value="addition">Other</option>

</select>
<br />
</fieldset>
<br />
<fieldset>
<legend>Your Message</legend>
<p>Message*</p><textarea name="message" rows="8" cols="29"></textarea><br /><p>
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="but"> &nbsp;<input type="reset" value="Clear" class="but">
</fieldset>
</form>

</body>
```

and now the main thing that is PHP goes this way ->

```html
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$priority = $_POST['priority'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Email: $email \n Website: $website \n Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "youremail@domain.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "$name submited the form.";
 if (filter_var("$email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        if ($email === "" || $message === "" || $name === "") {
echo "ERROR! Email and message and Name are Mandatory. <a href='contact.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Back</a>";
}
else { 
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!"); 
mail($email, "Name of Form Here", "Your Form has been submitted. Your problem will be noticed soon. This is a no reply mail address. Please dont reply back.  - WeBoosters India", "Thankyou") or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='index.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Home</a>";
}
 }
    else {
        echo "The email is not valid. Please write a proper email address. - <a href='contact.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'> Return Back</a>";
    }
?>
```

Hope you like it! Best of luck.

Comment: Sorry I posted the old version. Please remove all the 'domain' things out from the PHP. Thanks.

Comment: Now I have improved it Now you can get it fast and well!